# Compute the checksum for a binary file in Python

Tags: python, checksum

I have a binary file(2 bytes), whose content in Hex Format are as follows :

```
00 00 00 DD 11 22 33 44
```

In binary the content looks as follows(little endian format) :

```
11011101 00000000 00000000 00000000 01000100 00110011 00100010 00010001
```

I want to manually compute the checksum of the file and append it at the end of the file. For computing I am considering 4 bytes chunk at a time.

Then the manual steps should look as follows :

```
   11011101 00000000 00000000 00000000
+ 
   01000100 00110011 00100010 00010001
  --------------------------------------
=  00100001 00110011 00100010 00010001

   11011110 11001100 11011101 11101110  (1's complement)
+
   00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001  (add 1) <br/>
-----------------------------------------
=  11011110 11001100 11011101 11101111  (2's complement) = CheckSum
```

Please correct me, if I have computed the checksum wrongly.
Code I have written to compute the checksum in the system doesn't works fine.

```
add = 0
with open("temp.bin", "rb") as f:
    ## Read first 4 bytes of data
    byte = f.read(4)
    while byte != "":
        add += int.from_bytes(byte, byteorder="little")
    print(b"%02X" % (~add & 0xFFFFFFFF))
```

Please help me with the above problem and code.

Comment: Shouldn't checksum be a derivative of XOR result? BTW: here is the twos complement function in Python: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement

Comment: Do you _have_ to use this particular checksum? It would be faster to use one from the standard library (adler32, or crc32), since they run at C speed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't updating `byte` in your `while` loop, so the loop never ends.

You should keep reading from `f` until `byte` is `None`:

```
add = 0
with open("/temp/test.py", "rb") as f:
    ## Read first 4 bytes of data
    while True:
        byte = f.read(4)
        if not byte:
            break
        add += int.from_bytes(byte, byteorder='little')
    print(b'%02X' % (~add & 0xFFFFFFFF))
```